# Fetch small number of rows fast

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I'm not sure if my SQL has a problem or the problem lies with Oracle. We have a function on a web application that needs to display a table with a large number of entries (in the millions). However, the display only fetches 500  rows at a time. My guess was that this should be very fast.

The idea is to do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 500 <tablename> WHERE <where-clause>
```

The WHERE-clause is completely covered by an index. However, Oracle does not supply either `TOP` or `LIMIT`, so the alternative to use seems to be `ROW_NUMBER()` or OFFSET/FETCH FIRST.

However, when checking execution plans, it seems that even for the easiest queries, Oracle pretends it needs to read the full table before applying `ROW_NUMBER()` and filtering by it. The same for FETCH FIRST, because it seems that Oracle translates FETCH FIRST into a `ROW_NUMBER()` construct:

```
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=500)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY  NULL )<=500)
```

Example:

```
SELECT ID FROM <tablename> FETCH FIRST 500 ROWS ONLY;
```

Execution plan:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                      |  1643K|  5581M| 34399   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                  |                      |  1643K|  5581M| 34399   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY|                      |  1643K|  1234M| 34399   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | TABLENAME            |  1643K|  1234M| 34399   (1)| 00:00:03 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It gets more extreme with only one row, because the execution plan is the same. These costs are brutal for an operation resulting in a very low number of rows.

Is there a way to prevent Oracle to read all records before returning anything?

Edit 1:

As @Balasz-Papp below gets completely different execution plans, cardinalities and costs, I will document a complete example here.

This is a query just thrown together (there's an index covering only the id field):

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> ORDER BY id FETCH FIRST 500 ROWS ONLY;
```

The execution plan looks like this (gathered with both SQL Developer and TOAD):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |                      |  1643K|  5601M|       |   204K  (1)| 00:00:16 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                    |                      |  1643K|  5601M|       |   204K  (1)| 00:00:16 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK|                      |  1643K|  1234M|  1351M|   204K  (1)| 00:00:16 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | TABLE_NAME           |  1643K|  1234M|       | 34399   (1)| 00:00:03 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=500)
2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "EVENT"."ID")<=500)
```

Executing this statement takes a bit more than 14 minutes. The machine is not very performant, but the difference between selecting and returning 500 rows and selecting 1.6 million rows in almost 6GB and returning the first 500 seems to be what is happening.

Edit 2:

I've tried replicating the other way to generate the execution plan, using these statements for my example:

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ * from TABLE_NAME order by id fetch first 500 rows only;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'allstats last'));
```

The resulting plan looks like this:

```
Plan hash value: 4184280406                                                     

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                          
| Id  | Operation                | Name                 | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                          
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |                      |      1 |        |    500 |00:00:40.11 |   92135 |       |       |          |                          
|*  1 |  VIEW                    |                      |      1 |   1643K|    500 |00:00:40.11 |   92135 |       |       |          |                          
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK|                      |      1 |   1643K|    500 |00:00:40.11 |   92135 |   549K|   408K|  487K (0)|                          
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | MTR_EVENTPROTOCOL_TA |      1 |   1643K|   1645K|00:00:36.65 |   92135 |       |       |          |                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                          


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                             
---------------------------------------------------                             

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=500)               
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "EVENT"."ID")<=500)
```

Edit 3: Adding execution plan of a simple fetch by ID as requested:

```
Plan hash value: 612488378

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                      |     1 |   840 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MTR_EVENTPROTOCOL_TA |     1 |   840 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | MTR_EVENTPROTOCOL_PK |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("ID"=23417479)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY` operation is to stop the child operation after reaching the required amount of rows (without sorting). A `COUNT STOPKEY` operation is similar to that.

So no, the database does not read the whole table, and the above plan does not mean that.

Create a table with high number of rows:

```
SQL> create table t1 as select * from dba_objects;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 select * from t1;

23711 rows created.

SQL> /

47422 rows created.

SQL> /

94844 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select count(*) from t1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    189688

SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'T1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Select the 10 rows of it:

```
SQL> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ owner, object_name from t1 fetch first 10 rows only;

OWNER                          OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS                            OBJ$
...
10 rows selected.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'allstats last'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  5nv3z7ctvxamm, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ owner, object_name from t1 fetch
first 10 rows only

Plan hash value: 906235818

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |      |      1 |        |     10 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                  |      |      1 |     10 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY|      |      1 |     10 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | T1   |      1 |     10 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=10)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY  NULL )<=10)
```

As you can see, the database did not read the whole table, it estimated exactly 10 rows, and it stopped reading the table after retrieving exactly 10 rows, as requested.

**Ok, so here is an update because you have changed your example.**

```
SQL> delete from t1 where object_id is null;

8 rows deleted.

SQL> alter table t1 modify (object_id not null);

Table altered.

SQL> create index i1 on t1(object_id);

Index created.

SQL> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ owner, object_name from t1 order by object_id fetch first 10 rows only;

OWNER                          OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS                            C_OBJ#
...
10 rows selected.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'allstats last'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  9rj1zb98w8srh, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ owner, object_name from t1 order
by object_id fetch first 10 rows only

Plan hash value: 4198281070

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |      |      1 |        |     10 |00:00:00.01 |      13 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |      |      1 |     10 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |      13 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY       |      |      1 |     10 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |      13 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T1   |      1 |    189K|     10 |00:00:00.01 |      13 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN           | I1   |      1 |     10 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=10)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "OBJECT_ID")<=10)
```

Once again, the database does not read the whole table and not even the whole index, just what it needs for the first 10 rows. Note that I created a `NOT NULL` constraint on the indexed column. Indexes do not contain null values by default, so if your have null values in the indexed column, or you just simply do not have the `NOT NULL` constraint, the index will not be used and the whole table will be read:

```
SQL> alter table t1 modify (object_id null);

Table altered.

SQL> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ owner, object_name from t1 order by object_id fetch first 10 rows only;

OWNER                          OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS                            C_OBJ#
...
10 rows selected.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'allstats last'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  9rj1zb98w8srh, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ owner, object_name from t1 order
by object_id fetch first 10 rows only

Plan hash value: 2433988517

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |      |      1 |        |     10 |00:00:00.05 |    3216 |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  VIEW                    |      |      1 |     10 |     10 |00:00:00.05 |    3216 |       |       |          |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK|      |      1 |    189K|     10 |00:00:00.05 |    3216 |  2048 |  2048 | 2048  (0)|
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | T1   |      1 |    189K|    189K|00:00:00.02 |    3216 |       |       |          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=10)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "OBJECT_ID")<=10)
```

But if I "help" the database and tell it I do not need the null values(`where object_id is not null`), the index can be used again:

```
SQL> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ owner, object_name from t1 where object_id is not null order by object_id fetch first 10 rows only;

OWNER                          OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS                            C_OBJ#
...
10 rows selected.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'allstats last'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  24hf60f74stv3, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ owner, object_name from t1 where
object_id is not null order by object_id fetch first 10 rows only

Plan hash value: 4198281070

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |      |      1 |        |     10 |00:00:00.01 |      13 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |      |      1 |     10 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |      13 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY       |      |      1 |     10 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |      13 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T1   |      1 |    189K|     10 |00:00:00.01 |      13 |
|*  4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN           | I1   |      1 |     10 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=10)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "OBJECT_ID")<=10)
   4 - filter("OBJECT_ID" IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: You specifically recognizing the NULL values might be a problem lead us to discover that we are hitting an Oracle bug where there's a [patch available](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/community/oracle_database/4276490.html). Thank you.